# How to escape a full email address for SMTP in the headers when the email address contains non-ascii chars

Tags: email, unicode, encoding, smtp

It's about sending emails with non ASCII chars in the email address.

When I use send the TO /RCPT stuff to the SMTP server I know that I need to use punycode here.

But what about the To: and From: Header. Again I know that if the User friendly part contains a non ascii char I con use the standard header encoding that I also use for the subject. But this encoding is only used for the user friendly part.

But what if the email address contains a non ascii char? How must the To header be formatted.

So how to encode "Tüst" ?

This is the encoding as far as I know.

```
"=?iso-8859-1?Q?T=FCst?="<tüst@domain.de>
```

But what with the email address.

In fact: I don't understand the RFC's. I tried hard but failed.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: UTF-8 is the correct way to encode the header.

After some more research I found the answer hidden inside this article:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_email

> Although the traditional format for email header section allows
>   non-ASCII characters to be included in the value portion of some of
>   the header fields using MIME-encoded words (e.g. in display names or
>   in a Subject header field), MIME-encoding must not be used to encode
>   other information in a header, such as an email address, or header
>   fields like Message-ID or Received. Moreover, the MIME-encoding
>   requires extra processing of the header to convert the data to and
>   from its MIME-encoded word representation, and harms readability of a
>   header section.
>
> The 2012 standards RFC 6532 and RFC 6531 allow the inclusion of
>   Unicode characters in a header content using UTF-8 encoding, and their
>   transmission via SMTP - but in practice support is only slowly rolling
>   out.[5]